# Extending DefaultTableCellRenderer, no new object creation in getTableCellRendererComponent?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I've some difficulties to understand cell renderer. I want to use [`StretchIcon`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) in a `JTable`, so that cells of a column display a resized logo. `StretchIcon` extends `ImageIcon`.

Custom renderer:

```
public class IconCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon( (Icon) ( new StretchIcon((Image) value) ) );

        return label;
    }
}
```

This code works as desired, I've no problem with the table.

From this [tutorial](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=168), I learnt that I should avoid creating new objects in `getTableCellRendererComponent` for performance reason.

I don't understand:

- How many times will `IconCellRenderer` be instantiated. I assume only once, when the `JTable` is created (assuming I have only one column in the table).
- How many times will `getTableCellRendererComponent` be called. I assume once for each cell in the column, so that it can return a new instance of `JLabel` with an embedded instance of`StretchIcon` for each cell. If this is true, then it makes sense to create the new instances of JLabel and `StretchIcon` in the method.
- How will the resized icon be repainted when needed (cell being hidden and then shown again, or cell resized)? I assume `getTableCellRendererComponent` is not involved at all in this operation, and this is done entirely using the `paint` method of JLabel and the `paint` method redefined in `StretchIcon`.

Is my understanding somehow incorrect?
Is it legitimate to create a new instance of `StretchIcon` in the method?
What can I do to optimize this cell renderer, e.g. can I make the label object static?

---

Edit: based on comments and answer provided, I ended up with this cell renderer:

```
public class StretchIconRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private static StretchIcon stretched;

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, 
                isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        Image logo = (Image) value;

        if (stretched == null) { stretched = new StretchIcon(logo); }
        else { stretched.setImage(logo); }

        setIcon(stretched);
        setText(null);

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't create the `JLabel` in  the method. Just call `super.getTableCellRendererComponent` which returns the (I believe) default `JLabel` render component. Also, I haven't tried with `StretchIcon`, but I believe it's an `Icon`, for which you don't need a custom renderer. Just override `getColumnClass` in the model, and return `Icon` for the columns (Again I haven't tested. but you may want to try it). See [Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). The default renderer should render `ImageIcon` and `Icon` to an image

Comment: @mins `JLabel` extends from `Component`, so you don't need the cast, in fact you could simply return `this`...

Comment: @peeskillet: You provided me a very good guidance. DefaultTableCellRenderer extends JLabel. Reusing the label from supertype works (with a cast as the method returns a Component). Overriding model's method only works too (StretchIcon extends ImageIcon). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: You are right, using `this` as the `JLabel` for setting the image, and returning `this` is perfect. Appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How many times will `IconCellRenderer` be instantiated. I assume only once, when the JTable is created (assuming I have only one column in the table).

Technically, it only needs to be created once, but it may be created as often as you want.  Once assigned to a `JTable`/`TableColumn` however, it will never be initiated again by these classes.  They just maintain a reference to the instance you passed them

> How many times will `getTableCellRendererComponent` be called. I assume once for each cell in the column, so that it can return a new instance of JLabel with an embedded instance of `StretchIcon` for each cell. If this is true, then it makes sense to create the new instances of `JLabel` and `StretchIcon` in the method.

Yes, this is true, `getTableCellRendererComponent` will be called for each row in the table.  However, you don't need to create a new instance of components, you can return the same instance configured differently for each row.

The reason for this is, the table simple "paints" the result onto itself, it does not "add" the components in the manner you are use to.  This is often termed "cookie cutter" or "rubber stamping", as the component is used simply as a template.

> How will the resized icon be repainted when needed (cell being hidden and then shown again, or cell resized)? I assume `getTableCellRendererComponent` is not involved at all in this operation, and this is done entirely using the paint method of `JLabel` and the paint method redefined in `StretchIcon`.

No, this is done entirely via the `getTableCellRendererComponent`.  When a cell/row/column is updated in some way, a notification must be triggered from the `TableModel` or `ColumnModel`, which instructs the table that a change has occurred.

The table will determine the affected cells and repaint them, using the appropriate `TableCellRenderer`

In short.  There should be no need to create a new instance of `JLabel` within `getTableCellRendererComponent`.  In fact, you don't even need the `JLabel` at all, as `DefaultTableCellRenderer` extends from `JLabel` and you should simply use it.

I don't know how `StretchIcon` works, so you may have no choice but to create a new instance, but if you can, you might consider creating a `WeakHashMap` keyed to the `Object` value, which maintains a reference of `StretchIcon`, so you only ever create a single instance of for each row...

For example...

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    setIcon(getStretchIconFor(value));

    return this;
}

protected StreatchIcon(Object value) {
    StretchIcon icon = null;
    if (!cache.contains(value)) {
        icon = new StretchIcon((Image) value) );
        cache.put(value, icon);
    }
    return icon;
}
```

Where `cache` is a `WeakHashMap`...

In might be worth while having a read through [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Comment: This answer is really great and complete. Thanks for your time. Now that I've understood  @peeskillet's and your comment I can fully understand the details you provide. I learnt a lot from both of you. I didn't get at all the "rubber stamp" thing. Now I do, I may surely reuse StretchIcon instance as you explained, but in my case peeskillet's solution (overridding model getColumnClass and getValueAt) is sharper. No doubt I'll need a cell renderer soon and apply your instruction. Again thanks a lot, I'll +1 your answer with pleasure.

Comment: Remember, model is for data, it should not contain any UI components

Comment: Right. I keep the renderer (final code added in my question).